# Теряется тень у Button, свойство elevation не срабатывает

Tags: java, android, android-studio, material-design

При установке тени (свойства elevation) для Button все отлично работает в режиме дизайна, в Android Studio все отображается, но при запуске приложения тень теряется, не могу понять в чем дело. Эмуляцию провожу на устройстве с версией 4.4, также пробовал тестить и на реальном устройстве

```
  <Button
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@color/blueColor"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/checkPassbutton"
    android:text="@string/enter_into_programm"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
    android:stateListAnimator="@null"
    android:elevation="6dp"/>
```

Comment: elevation работает только с 21 API (5.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Предпросмоторщику в студии не стоит доверять как и вовсе им пользоваться.
2. Как верно пишут в [комментариях](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/504417/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C-%D1%83-button-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-elevation-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82#comment605085_504417) - elevation работает только с 21 API (5.0), а значит на андроиде меньше 5-ой версии это свойство просто игнорируется.

Comment: Спасибо, пришлось поискать альтернативу свойству elevation, нашел следующее по ссылке, может кому понадобиться: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13005714/how-to-show-shadow-around-the-linearlayout-in-android

Comment: В предпросмоторщике можно выбрать уровень API и тип устройства. Это позволяет получить быстрое превью для разных ситуаций. Поэтому им очень даже стоит пользоваться )